# Is "Expires“ in http header useful?

Tags: http, frontend

Is there a default behavior for cache of static files like images/js/css in browsers?
Even if I did not set the expires on my server, I found that my browser(Firefox, IE8) could also read the static files from local cache, so is the "Expires" useful?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's absolutely useful. If you don't set the header, the client must *guess* when the content expires. You may not like how it guesses, and some browsers are more or less aggressive than others. Please read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx for a full discussion.